# Which one is correct "John is in the third" or "John is in the third place"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, ordinal-numbers, esl

If I want to ask someone in the picture, like 'Where's John?' or 'Which one is john?' which answer should it be?

Comment: Neither. Try ELL site.

Comment: Either of those questions will allow someone to tell you which person in the picture is John. I'm afraid what you have written here isn't very clear, because of the words "What answer should it be?" -- note that **that's** the question which Max has answered below.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"John is in the third" doesn't make sense, "John is in the third place" is technically correct but reads oddly. "John is the third one/person" would work. Maybe specifying which direction, but generally we'd assume from the left.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: "John is third" or "John is third from the left" also seems fine to me.